# jquery add class no responding

Tags: jquery

I have defined this classes:

```
.OldClass
{
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  height: 25px;
}
.NewClass
{
  align-right: 50px;

}
```

And the control for it:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="OneLabel" CssClass="OldClass myClass"> ></asp:Label>
```

In jquery i want to replace OldClass, with NewClass with no success, where am i wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        $("OneLabel").addClass("NewClass");

    });
</script>
```

I've tried also with `$("#<%=OneLabel.ClientID%>").addClass`

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using ASP.Net webforms, the `id` of the control is changed at runtime. Therefore you need to use the following:

```
$("#<%= OneLabel.ClientID %>").addClass('NewClass');
```

The second propeblem is that the `align-right` property does not exist. If you're trying to make the element move `50px` to the right, add some `padding-left`:

```
.NewClass {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect, use # to point at id.

```
$("#OneLabel").addClass("NewClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#OneLabel").addClass("NewClass");`

Use # for id selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {        
        $("#OneLabel").removeClass("OldClass").addClass("NewClass");
    });
</script>
```

First you need to remove the class `OldClass` and add the class `NewClass` and Since `OneLabel` is an **id** you need to select it like `#Id`.If it is an tag like `div` , `span`  you can directly select it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the class do the following:

```
$("#OneLabel").removeClass("OldClass").addClass("NewClass");
```

This [selects the DOM element by id](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), [removes the given class](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [adds the new one](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

Answer (score 0):

To replace all Oldclass to NewClass :

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
   if($("#OneLabel").hasClass("OldClass"))  
     $("#OneLabel").removeClass("OldClass");
     $("#OneLabel").addClass("NewClass");

});
```